# How to convert dynamic list List<object> to object list List<Customer>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to convert my dynamic list `List<object>` to `List<Customer>`.
Dynamic list has total 10 properties (Id, Name, PhoneNo, Address, SecodaryPhone, Email etc) and Customer class has only Id, Name and PhoneNo.
I want to convert the list so that it will copy the list with mapping properties.

I can not use the name of dynamic properties as this can any other like storing other types let say Products.

Comment: What about `AutoMapper`?

Comment: What about using `listofObject.Select(x => new Customer { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, PhoneNo = x.PhoneNo }).ToList();`? But you need to show your effort to convert both lists before trying suggested code above.

Comment: Is your :dynamic list" actually a `List<dynamic>` or do you just mean the actual types of the members might differ at different times? Or that the list contains multiple differing types? What does your last sentence mean?

Answer (score 0):

Install the AutoMapper NuGet package. Then you can cast your list like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        dynamic person = new { Name = "John", Id = 10 };

        var people = new List<dynamic>() { person };
        var cusomters = people.Select(p => mapper.Map<Customer>(p)).ToList();
    }
}

class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

Alternatively, if you don't want to use AutoMapper, you could try something like this:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic people = new { Name = "John", Id = 10 };

        var list = new List<dynamic>() { people };
        var result = list.Select(p => new Customer(p)).ToList();
    }
}

class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Customer(dynamic arg)
    {
        Name = arg.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some extensions to make working with `MemberInfo` easier:

```
// ***
// *** Type Extensions
// ***
public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
    t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field | mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

// ***
// *** MemberInfo Extensions
// ***
public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}
public static T GetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) => (T)member.GetValue(srcObject);

public static void SetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, T value) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            mfi.SetValue(destObject, value);
            break;
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            mpi.SetValue(destObject, value);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}
```

You can use this extension to copy matching object member values to another type:

```
// Convert any object to another Type by copying over common properties or fields
public static T ToType<T>(this object obj) where T : new() {
    var ansObj = new T();
    var ansFields = typeof(T).GetPropertiesOrFields().ToDictionary(pf => pf.Name);

    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetPropertiesOrFields())
        if (ansFields.TryGetValue(prop.Name, out var destpf))
            destpf.SetValue(ansObj, prop.GetValue(obj));

    return ansObj;
}
```

So your final result would be:

```
var ans = sourceList.Select(m => m.ToType<Customer>()).ToList();
```

But I think you would be much better off using interfaces and having a common base interface:

```
interface IIDBase {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}

public class Products : IIDBase {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then you just cast to a `List<IIDBase>`:

```
var ans = sourceList.Cast<IIDBase>().Select(m => new Customer {
              Id = m.Id,
              Name = m.Name,
              PhoneNo = m.PhoneNo
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you can use `dynamic`.

```
var list = new List<object>(new [] 
{
    new DynamicObject {Id = $"{1}", Name = $"Name{1}", PhoneNo = $"555-000{1}-1234"},
    new DynamicObject {Id = $"{2}", Name = $"Name{2}", PhoneNo = $"555-000{2}-1234"},
    new DynamicObject {Id = $"{3}", Name = $"Name{3}", PhoneNo = $"555-000{3}-1234"},
});
var customers = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)list).Select(x => new Customer{ Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, PhoneNo = x.PhoneNo}).ToArray();
Customer customer = customers.First();



class DynamicObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string SecodaryPhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}
```